# Unable to find where data persisted in MySQL using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

1. I created a database in MySQL named newlmstest
2. Created a Java Web Application in Netbeans with JFS and Primefaces
3. Created the persistence.xml with the wizard (with table generation strategy - create)
4. Single entity was created.
5. Created JSF pages from entity classes using the wizard

Everything works fine and data persists.

But I'm unable to find the table created in the "newlmstest" database.

Where is my data saved?

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="primefaces-jsf-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newlmstest?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="()"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

UnitFacade.java

```
@Stateless
public class UnitFacade extends AbstractFacade<Unit> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primefaces-jsf-pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UnitFacade() {
        super(Unit.class);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But unable to find the table"? Are you using a MySQL client to connect to the database and check the table manually? Are you using some kind of GUI to look for the tables? Are you trying to read the data back into the application? Please specify exactly, what you are trying to do and what is not working as expected.

Comment: With the application you can add, edit, delete and view data. All is there.

But with PhpMyadmin and Heidi no luck. DB is empty !

Comment: That sounds like you are looking at a different DB than your application is using.

Comment: What are the places in a Java Web Maven project that holds the data on the used DB?
Do they reside outside the project too ? ie. in the IDE

Comment: If you are using a database like MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, etc, your IDE has nothing to do with the database. You had installed these databases earlier and usually, the installer asks where to save the databases on your available storage devices.